# Affecting Fullcalendar today button .fc-today-button

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm having trouble getting custom controls to work when clicking the 'today' button that is part of Fullcalendar.

All the documentation I can find tells me that Fullcalendar's built-in controls can be affected using two methods:

So, this one works for me when it's applied to previous, next, month, agendaWeek and agendaDay, but not for 'today' (`button.fc-today-button`):

```
    $('body').on('click', 'button.fc-next-button', function() {
            console.log('I Clicked Next');
    });
```

Some documentation also say that this works, although I can't make it do so on any button:

```
    $('.fc-next-button span').click(function(){
            console.log('I Clicked Next');
    });
```

Does anyone know why this is and what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation and the help of MikeSmithDev (thanks Mike - your help was invaluable), it appears as though the 'today' event only gets triggered if it physically positioned below/after the calendar, the rest of the header controls (`button.fc-next-button` etc) don't seem to mind where they are physically positioned.

Likely the first function executes before the calendar is finished loading... so it works, there is just no button to bind it to.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you want to affect the "today" button, yet you are adding code for the "next" button. You want to do something like:

```
$(".fc-today-button").click(function() {
    alert('Clicked Today!');
});
```

This applies a click event to anything with the class "fc-today-button" (that is the class that the Today button will have).

Working example:

```js
$('#fullCal').fullCalendar({
    events: [{
        title: 'Event 1',
        start:  moment().add(1, 'h'),
        end: moment().add(2, 'h'),
        allDay: false
    }], 
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'prev title next today',
        right: ''
    },
    timezone:'local',
    defaultDate: '2014-11-15',
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: false,
    firstDay: 6,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
});
               
$(".fc-today-button").click(function() {
    alert('Clicked Today!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="fullCal"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer but it's not that I'm afraid. I was just using 'next' as an example. Here's jsfiddle.net/t1nm4Lf2 to have a look at. It's a stripped down version of what my calendar does and illustrates the problem I'm having. I know that the fiddle doesn't work 100%, but my calendar does, every element of it except the 'today' button.

Comment: @user783322 My answer works, which if you "Run code snippet", you will see that it does what you expect it to do. [Here is your working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1nm4Lf2/5/) which *also* works once I updated it to use the correct script source for qtip.

Comment: @user783322 so what that means is the problem wasn't the `today` click event, but a bad js reference... Anyway, now you have two working examples. Hopefully that solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks Mike, apologies for the incorrect reference in the fiddle, that was my mistake. I have researched this further and the problem appears to be down to the sequence that the calls are in relation to the calendar call. You can see what I mean here http://jsfiddle.net/t1nm4Lf2/12/. It appears as though the 'today' event only gets triggered if it physically positioned below/after the calendar, the rest of the header controls don't seem to mind where they are physically positioned. Is this behaviour explainable?

Comment: Likely the first function executes before the calendar is finished loading... so it works, there is just no button to bind it to. [see the same function](http://jsfiddle.net/t1nm4Lf2/13/) just delayed by 1s.

Comment: That makes sense. Glad to get to the bottom of it and thanks for your help. End.

Comment: @user783322 any reason why this isn't accepted as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to more or less achieve this with a native workaround of sorts. You may utilize the "customButtons" and "headerToolbar" in combination to effectively remove the original today button and replace it with your own which can trigger custom function code upon being clicked.

I'm actually using this with VueJS, but should be equally feasible with Vanilla JS.

```
// these are the options you can pass when initializing a fullcalendar
    customButtons: {
      focusButton: {
        text: "focus",
        click: this.scrollToCurrentDay // this is a vue component function, but you could just as well pass a vanilla JS function
      }
    },
    headerToolbar: { // this effectively removes the original today button and adds our custom button to the header of the calendar
      left: '',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'prev focusButton next'
    }
```

I wanted to do this because I wanted to not only focus the month when today was clicked, but also to scroll the calendar to the day (useful when using small screens like phones).

My custom today button click handler:

```
scrollToCurrentDay: function(arg) {
  let CalendarAPI = this.$refs.calendar.getApi();
  CalendarAPI.today();
  var todayElement = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-day-today')[0];
  var calendarElement = document.getElementsByClassName('fc')[0];
  if (todayElement) {
    todayElement.scrollIntoView();
  } else {
    calendarElement.scrollIntoView();
  }
},
```